# Django Copy multiple items from DB Query to dict

Tags: python, django, dictionary

i have a Problem with Django and dicts. I want to get only items that match a sting as below. but i can´t get it to work. Thanks for your help.

```
django_db_query = [{'time': '13:00 Uhr', 'titel': 'test1'}, {'time': '14:00 blah', 'titel': 'test2'}, {'time': '13:00 Uhr', 'titel': 'test3'},]
all_db_items = Django_db.objects.all()

only_13 = dict()
for item in all_db_items:
    if item.time is "13":
        only_13 += item
```

---

wanted: The datastructure and multiple values from my db in my dict but only with time 13:00 Uhr

```
for item in only_13:
    print item.titel

console
   test1
   test2
```

Comment: could you provide us with your model definition?

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in all_db_items:
    if item['time'] == "13:00 Uhr":
        only_13.update(item)
```

`is` only works with *identical* operands

`+` is not implemented for dicts, use `update` instead

more resources:
https://www.python-course.eu/dictionaries.php

Comment: can you give an example for an `item` and one for `item.time`?

Comment: updated my answer according to your model definition

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DjangoDbModel looks something like

```
def DjangoDbModel(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

All you need to do in that case is
`DjangoDbModels.objects.filter(time__hour=13)` if you want to have only items that are from hour 13. You can apply similar filters to the day, year and month for example.

Comment: i already tried to go this way, but later i will only have items that are > than my current time. i think this will not work with db querys

Comment: Sure it will! Change your CharField to be a DateTimeField and you can flexibly query on it :) `range` should work great for example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#range

Comment: i think i dont get the definition of an queryset and dictionary,

Comment: in my code i load the database query into my variable all_db_item

later in my code i create the dict context and create in context the key db, with the value all_db_items

this is going to my template and jinga can access it by
    `{% for item in db %}`
             `<li>{{  item.titel }}</li>`
    `{% endfor %}
please explan me how my dictionary can hold more than just one value.
i mean why can i interate over an dictionary value? how is it seperated?

and how can i rebuild it in a selfmade dictionary? o.O